# Cannot upload many files to Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon

I have a problem with Orbeon Forms 2017.1. When I try to upload multiple attachments to my form in Form Runner one by one I get error message:

> There was an error during the upload. Please try again.

I saw that Orbeon throws an error in page inspect:

> VM3031:1 POST http://:18080/orbeon/xforms-server/upload 413
>   (Request Entity Too Large)

Web Server: Tomcat 8
Operation System: CentOS

Comment: It might be issue [#3329](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3329). We will issue Orbeon Forms 2017.1.1 PE soon.

Comment: For completeness, and to help people who might find this through search, since Orbeon Forms PE 2017.1.1 has been released, I've posted an answer below.

Comment: Thank you, fix for #3329 solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've hit [issue #3329](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3329). This issue had been fixed in [Orbeon Forms PE 2017.1.1](http://blog.orbeon.com/2017/09/orbeon-forms-201711-pe.html). So my recommendation would be for you to [download](http://www.orbeon.com/download) and upgrade to that version.

Comment: Kamil, excellent, I am glad it did, and thank you for confirming.